# Geolocation SOQL query

Tags: geolocation, soql

I am trying to write a simple trigger on the case object to find the closest account to a given zip code. For simplicity I'll provide only the lines which are causing the error.

//This is a custom object which has all US zip codes with lat and lng info

```
        ZipCodeGeolocation__c zipGl = [SELECT GeoLoc__Latitude__s, GeoLoc__Longitude__s
                                         FROM ZipCodeGeolocation__c
                                        WHERE Name = :c.Zip_Code__c
                                        LIMIT 1];


        List<Account> nearCenters = new List<Account>([SELECT Name, Email__c
                                                         FROM Account
                                                        WHERE DISTANCE (BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION( :zipGl.GeoLoc__Latitude__s, :zipGl.GeoLoc__Longitude__s), 'mi' ) < 50
                                                     ORDER BY DISTANCE (BillingAddress, GEOLOCATION( :zipGl.GeoLoc__Latitude__s, :zipGl.GeoLoc__Longitude__s), 'mi' )]);
```

Every time I add the "ORDER BY" clause, I get the following error:
"An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1398691353-5783 (-929716091)"
Obviously the Error Id is different every time. Has anyone seen this behavior before and what can I do to solve this issue?
Thank you

Comment: How can you order by your result when that target order by fields are not in your selection ?

Comment: I did try to include the fields in the SELECT statement to no avail.